# How to create a title page like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I think this title page style suit my document very much, but it is made in MS Word. I think it's possible to make such title page style in LaTeX using Ti*k*Z, but I think I am not good enough in Ti*k*Z to complete such a task.

[image]

May you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Hi, you could/should provide a non such good code that you tried till now and surely you will get much more possibilities to get a good answer

Comment: @Karlo Well, for the MWE, I declare that I don't have even a single idea. I have been using TikZ to draw geomery figures only. So I haven't tried at all -- and that's why I can't even provide a MWE :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How is it possible that you can post pretty good answers but not even an MWE here? (And sorry, I am not in the mood to type things in from your screen shot, so I just add some random text.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{innerblue}{RGB}{134,159,202}
\definecolor{middleblue}{RGB}{213,222,236}
\definecolor{outerblue}{RGB}{173,190,220}
\definecolor{bggray}{RGB}{215,215,215}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
triple circle/.style={code={
\fill[outerblue] (4,0) circle (4);
\fill[middleblue] (3.1,0) circle (3.1);
\fill[innerblue] (2.2,0) circle (2.2);
}}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[bggray] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east); 
\draw[blue!60] ([xshift=-1cm]current page.north) 
-- ++ (-60:9) pic[rotate=90-60,scale=0.7] {triple circle};
\draw[blue!60] (current page.north west) 
-- ++ (-40:20) pic[rotate=90-40,scale=0.3] {triple circle};
\draw[blue!60] ([yshift=-11cm]current page.north east) 
-- ++ (-110:15) pic[rotate=90-110,scale=0.8] {triple circle};
\node[above right=8cm and 2cm of current page.south west,font=\Huge\bfseries,blue!90] (H)
{Hamanostoros};
\node[below=2mm of H.south west,anchor=north west,font=\sffamily]{Master of
Philosophy};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice effort ...

Comment: Well, for the MWE, I declare that I don't have even a single idea. I have been using TikZ to draw geomery figures only. So I haven't tried at all -- and that's why I can't even provide a MWE :D